# jQuery .position() strangeness while using CSS3 rotate attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I'm getting absolutely positioned rotated elements position with jQuery `.position()` method, then setting position-related attributes (top, left) with jQuery `.css(pos)`, where `pos` is the data returned by `.position()`. I think it'll leave the element in it's place, but elements position is changing.

How can I use set rotated elements position, so that it'll be placed as expected? Maybe there is a coefficient depended on angle that changes position?

I'm testing in Google Chrome v.9, Windows XP.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="element"> 
    <img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0Fawya9MVMez80ZusMVtk_4-ScKCIy6J_fg84oZ37GzKaJXU74Ma0vENc"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;   
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;
}    
#element {
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left: 60px;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $el = $('#element'),
    // getting position    
        pos = $el.position();
    alert(pos.left + '/' + pos.top);
    // alerts 37/11

    // setting css position attributes equal to pos
    $el.css(pos);
    // re-getting position
    pos = $el.position();
    alert(pos.left + '/' + pos.top);
    // alerts 14/-28
});
```

View it http://jsfiddle.net/Antaranian/2gVL4/

Comment: One obvious solution would be to straighten up the image temporarily whenever you read/write its position properties...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Šime, I thought about it too, but it'll have a big effect on productivity of the whole app, and user will feel is visually, so I'm looking for the more intelligent way to solve it.

Comment: It works in Opera and Firefox both alerting  `50/60`.

Comment: @Poetro It works in Opera because the image is not rotated in that browser. Add `-o-transform: rotate(45deg);` to the #element CSS rules and it won't work in Opera, too.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm about Google Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Needed to read the "real" position
$.fn.adjustedPosition = function() {
    var p = $(this).position();
    return {
        left: p.left - this.data('dx'),
        top: p.top - this.data('dy')
    }
};
```

---

```
$(function() { 

    var img = $('img'),
        pos;

    // Calculate the delta
    img.each(function() {
        var po = $(this).position(), // original position
            pr = $(this).addClass('rot').position(); // rotated position

        $(this).data({
            dx: pr.left - po.left, // delta X
            dy: pr.top - po.top // delta Y
        });
    });

    // Read the position
    pos = img.adjustedPosition();    
    alert(pos.left + '/' + pos.top);     

    // Write the position
    img.css(pos);

    // Read the position again
    pos = img.adjustedPosition();    
    alert(pos.left + '/' + pos.top);

});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2gVL4/4/

So what is going on here:

1. The CSS code that rotates the image is stored inside a special CSS class. I do this because I want to read the original position of the image (before rotating). Once I read that original position, I apply the `.rot` class, and then read the position again to calculate the difference (delta), which is stored inside the element's data().
2. Now, I can read the position via the custom method `adjustedPosition` (which is defined above). This method will read the position of the element and then subtract the delta values stored inside the data() of the element.
3. To write the position, just use the `css(pos)` method like normally.

Comment: Maybe there's a browser problem here (using firefox) but after updating the fiddle to use transform: rotate() it doesn't get the new positions after rotating.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem. There is simple solution (not elegant, but working):

- set current angle to 0
- read X/Y position
- revert angle back to its value

  ```
  var temp = $(this).position();
  temp.angle = getRotationDegrees( $(this) );            // remember current angle
  rotateObject($(this), 0);                              // set angle to 0
  temp.left = Math.round($(this).position().left);       // proper value
  temp.top = Math.round($(this).position().top);         // proper value

  // revert back the angle
  rotateObject($(this), temp.angle);
  ```

Used functions:

```
    function rotateObject(obj, angle) {
        obj.css({ '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
        obj.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
        obj.css({ '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
        obj.css({ 'msTransform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
        obj.css({ '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
        obj.css({ '-sand-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
        obj.css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
    }

    function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
        var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
        obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
        obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
        obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
        obj.css("transform");
        if(matrix !== 'none') {
            var tr;
            if (tr = matrix.match('matrix\\((.*)\\)')) {
                tr = tr[1].split(',');
                if(typeof tr[0] != 'undefined' && typeof tr[1] != 'undefined') {
                    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(tr[1], tr[0]) * (180/Math.PI));
                }else{
                    var angle = 0; 
                }
            }else if(tr = matrix.match('rotate\\((.*)deg\\)')){
                var angle = parseInt(tr[1]); 
            }
        } else { var angle = 0; }
        return (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
    }
```