# jQuery's .position conflicts with CSS3's transform 

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem on jQuery `.position` function.

It conflicts with the transform rotate of CSS3.

I am getting the position left and right of an image inside the rotated div.

The result of `.position` if I rotated my DIV is different when the div is not rotated.

Here is the CSS of the div:

```
#a{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$("#img").click(function(){
    alert($(this).position().left);
    alert($(this).position().top);
})
```

Comment: What is the issue? whats the error?

Comment: Your code appears to be incomplete. You give us the CSS for the `#a` element and the JavaScript for the `#img` element. What is the relationship of these two elements?

Comment: wouldn't the left/top be different since it is rotated? If a rotate a `100x50` rectangle with position `left: 5, top:10` 90 degrees. It would now be more like a `50x100` rectangle with position `left: 10, top:5` would it not?

Comment: #img is inside the #a div

Here is the result of the position of the image

not yet rotated:
0px left 0px top

rotated:
100.000003814px left 0px top

Comment: You're quite right about this issue, I have run into the same problem. Rotating the div shifts its actual left value (calculated as the left-most corner of the box) but jquery returns its left value calculated prior to rotating. I've worked around this by figuring out what the new "real" left value is and manually subtracting the pixels.

Comment: The issue isn't that the position values change as the result of a rotation (they _absolutely should_ in my opinion, since the position of the element _has_ changed).  The issue is that 1) whether or not the value changes seems to depend upon the browser used, and 2) when the value _does_ change, it doesn't accurately reflect the element's new position (in particular, 'top' appears accurate, while 'left' does not track the element properly).  Only solution I've found is to account for the inconsistencies manually.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though `.offset()` and `.position()` give different outputs in different browsers, here's a test: http://jsfiddle.net/F8Jtt/5/

Here is a similar question with an accepted answer: [jQuery .position() strangeness while using CSS3 rotate attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078897/jquery-position-strangeness-while-using-css3-rotate-attribute)

Comment: hmm I want to know how to get the position of the image #img inside my div #a

Answer (score 1):

Is bug of jquery: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8362 and http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6844
jQuery use offsetParent() with while of possitions but not calcule rotation and scale parents. jQuery dont support CSS3.