# Div position slightly offset when using jquery draggable with HTML local storage

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a draggable div element that uses HTML 5 localStorage to remember its position on the users page. This works fine.

I'm also using the `window.addEventListener` to update the position if the div was dragged in another open tab. This works but the div's position in one browser tab is slightly offset to the div in the another tab. Does anyone know what is causing this?

A basic example is below. Save it as an html file and open it up in two different tabs to see what is happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .note
    {
        position: absolute;
        width:200px;
        height:220px;
        background: #2E2E2E;
        top: 50px;
        left: 50px;

     transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(7deg);
    }


    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {


            var note = $(".note");
            updatePosition(note);

            note.draggable({ stop: function () {

                var left = $(this).position().left;
                var top = $(this).position().top;

                localStorage.setItem("left", left);
                localStorage.setItem("top", top);

            }
            });

            window.addEventListener("storage", function (e) {
                updatePosition(note);
            }, 

            false);


        });

            function updatePosition(note) {

            var left = localStorage.getItem("left");
            var top = localStorage.getItem("top");
            note.css({ left: left + "px", top: top + "px" });

            }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="note"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: Its the CSS transformation properties that are causing the offset.

Comment: +1, excellent question. I wish more people asked questions this way...

Comment: This is a really convient question, as we can paste the source code right into a file locally, without having to worry about where the jquery library will be included from.

Comment: It seems like if I have this file opened in 2 different tabs and I move one div, the other div will move as well on the other tab. Weird!

Comment: It's not weird that's what it's meant to do! The problem is that they aren't in exactly the same position - they're slightly offset from eachother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this bug?  http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8362

I see that your JS is doing everything right but jQuery is returning the wrong value from .css().

Here's a working example:  http://db.tt/gCHuZ7zz

And the relevant code changes:

```
        note.draggable({ stop: function () {

            var left = this.offsetLeft;
            var top = this.offsetTop;

            localStorage.setItem("left", left);
            localStorage.setItem("top", top);

        }
        });



        function updatePosition(note) {

        var left = localStorage.getItem("left");
        var top = localStorage.getItem("top");
        note.css({ left: left + "px", top: top + "px" });

        note[0].offsetTop = top;
        note[0].offsetLeft = left

        }
```

Comment: Have you noticed that the css transform also causes the div to be a bit snappy/jolty when you click on it to drag? This looks like another jQuery bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6844. Know any work arounds to this aswell?

Comment: No experience personally but it looks like there is a jQuery Transformable plugin that has a better draggable() function...the hosting site is down but here's  a Fiddle using it:  http://jsfiddle.net/aflin/MhGPU/

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem here using Chrome's inspector.

`$(".note").position()` is different from the real `left` and `top` of `note`

This is because you rotated the element, you can see for yourself by removing the `transform` in the css.
A fix can be found here: [jQuery .position() strangeness while using CSS3 rotate attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078897/jquery-position-strangeness-while-using-css3-rotate-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  var left = this.offsetLeft;
  var top = this.offsetTop;
```

instead of

```
  var left = $(this).position().left;
  var top = $(this).position().top;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in transformation properties of the css class. Actually, it is the behavior of html5 local storage.

**Local Storage:**

- Values persist beyond windows and browsers lifetime.
- Values are shared across every window or tab running at the same origin.

Now, look at your code you set and get the position of div in local storage. And when div is drag your 'window' event listener is fired which gets the position from local storage and update the position. So, that's why on different tabs of a browser div retain the same position.

And you should try this

```
var left = this.offsetLeft;
var top = this.offsetTop;
```